# Kibana plugins to edit documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'd like to use Kibana + Elasticsearch as a tool for application failures investigation.

This is how I see that: application logs all failures, some responsible engineer (me) see that new unknown failures appeared on Kibana's dashboard, investigates why failures happened and than marks related documents with specific attribute.

Unfortunately, the only way to update documents from Kibana UI I found so far are raw queries from "Dev tools".

Maybe there are some plugins that allow documents editing via fancy UI?